# Increase() vs changes() function for counters

Tags: prometheus

I have a gift-certificates application that increases Prometheus counter whenever someone activates a certificate.

Now I want to put simple number in Grafana board that shows me how many certificates were activated last 24h.

I can do that by `increase(gift_certificates_activated_total[24h])` query, but it gives float results, something like `105.01287565915334`.

But what I found is if I use changes function, it gives me the exact integer result. Query is: `changes(gift_certificates_activated_total[24h])` and it shows exactly 105.

Docs says

> For each input time series, changes(v range-vector) returns the number of times its value has changed within the provided time range as an instant vector.

As far as I understood, that it's suitable for gauge metric types to get the number of changes of gauge metric value, not for counter. But it seems to work fine with counters too. It shows the same result as `floor(increase(gift_certificates_activated_total[24h]))` query.

Is it appropriate usage of changes() function?

Comment: The difference is that `changes` records how many times it changed in the interval. If you ever change the value by more than 1, they will return different. As in, "increase by 10", `increase(...)` should return 10, `changes(...)` should return 1 (you changed it once, by 10).  However, the reason `increase` returns a floating point number is that the start and end is interpolated to compensate for them not being exactly at minute boundaries or similar. It should work out just fine.

Comment: Additionally, since every point on your graph is going to cover an area neighboring points also cover, unless you plot only once every 24 hours, then it shouldn't matter if your values are off by +/- 1, you're looking for the big picture, trends. You're not going to grab those values and sum them and wonder why it's off by 1. ... would be my guess.

Answer (score 6):

The `changes()` function in Prometheus can be used instead of `increase()` function if you are sure that the counter stays the same or is incremented by 1 between scrapes. If the counter is incremented by more than 1, then `changes()` will return lower results than `increase()`.

The `increase()` function in Prometheus may return fractional results for integers counters because of interpolation. See more details [here](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/issues/1215#issuecomment-850305711).

Note also that both `changes(m[d])` and `increase(m[d])` in Prometheus may miss the difference between the last samples just before the lookbehind window `d` and the first point at the window. Both issues mentioned above are resolved in [MetricsQL](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html) though. (I'm the author of MetricsQL).